# Plotly R: highlight the hovered label in pie chart and grey out the other labels

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

Dataframe:

```
df2 = data.frame(value = c(9, 2, 7, 3, 6),
                 key = c('ar', 'or', 'br', 'gt', 'ko'))
```

And this is the code to generate the pie chart:

```
df2 %>% 
  plot_ly(labels = ~key,
          values = ~value,
          type = 'pie')
```

Basically, I would like to highlight the label that I'm hovering over and grey out the other labels, like these plots: [1st plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8pqk.png) and [2nd plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ddow1.png).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a gray and default color array and used the point you hover on as a replacer in the array of all gray colors, then it's sent to the graph as a `plotly_restyle`. If you're familiar with how `updatemenus` works for buttons, it's essentially the same coding, just in JS instead of R.

```
library(htmlwidgets)
library(plotly)

df2 = data.frame(value = c(9, 2, 7, 3, 6),
                 key = c('ar', 'or', 'br', 'gt', 'ko'))


hoverer = "function(el, x) {
            el.on('plotly_hover', function(d){
              var pn;
              var oCol = ['#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e', '#2ca02c', '#d62728', '#9467bd'];
              var nCol = ['gray','gray','gray','gray','gray'];
              pn = d.points[0].pointNumber;
              nCol[pn] = oCol[pn];
              var update = {marker:{colors: nCol}};
              Plotly.restyle(el.id, update);
            });
            el.on('plotly_unhover', function(d){
              var oCol = ['#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e', '#2ca02c', '#d62728', '#9467bd'];
              var update = {marker:{colors: oCol}};
              Plotly.restyle(el.id, update);
            });}"


df2 %>% 
  plot_ly(labels = ~key,
          values = ~value,
          # default colors; matches JS
          marker = list(colors = list('#1f77b4',  # muted blue
                                      '#ff7f0e',  # safety orange
                                      '#2ca02c',  # cooked asparagus green
                                      '#d62728',  # brick red
                                      '#9467bd')),# muted purple))
          type = 'pie') %>% onRender(hoverer) # this is from htmlwidgets library
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! Also, Do you think there's a way to do it without actually knowing JS?

Comment: I wouldn't have used JS if I knew a method that worked with R alone. While JS isn't nearly as forgiving as R, it's still not nearly as exacting as languages like C(s) or Java. If you are fairly confident in R, it's not that big of a leap to begin working with Javascript.